# How can I use the src imports in Vue3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I wanna ask you how can I use a component in VUE3 with composition API -> script setup pattern, for eg. -> I have a component: Modal. So I'm gonna create a folder Modal which has:

1. Modal.vue -> where is the vue template and import the script and scss like this:  `<script src="./index.js">`  
   `<style lang="scss" scoped>   @import './style.scss'; </style>`
2. index.js -> where is the js code. **Here is the problem!! If I'm trying to use the `<script setup>` the code here isn't working. Any idea why?**
3. style.scss -> where is the css style.

SPA:

```
<template>
  <div class="modals">
    <h1>Modals</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
/*
  imports
*/

import { ref } from 'vue';
import Modal from '@/components/Modal.vue';
import ModalDark from '@/components/ModalDark.vue';

/*
  modals
*/

const showDarkModals = ref(false);
const showModal = ref(false);

const hideModal = () => (showModal.value = false);
const displayModal = () => showModal.value = true;
</script>
```

And I want something like this:

A folder called Modal and which have the following structure:
[image]

index.vue

```
<template>
   <div class="modals">
        <h1>Modals</h1>
   </div>
</template>
    
<script src="./index.js" setup></script>
    
<style> @import './style.css'; </style>
```

index.js

```
/*
  imports
*/
<script>

import { ref } from 'vue';
import Modal from '@/components/Modal.vue';
import ModalDark from '@/components/ModalDark.vue';

/*
  modals
*/

const showDarkModals = ref(false);
const showModal = ref(false);

const hideModal = () => (showModal.value = false);
const displayModal = () => showModal.value = true;
</script>
```

style.css

```
.modals {
  background: red;
}
```

---

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

- **reference:** https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-spec.html#src-imports

Comment: Can you provide us the code in the `.js`-file and the exact problem (error message, or expected and actual behaviour)?

Comment: I just updated the description of the question.

Answer (score -1):

You must just not wrap the content of the `.js`-file with `script` tags, since you are not writing this code in an HTML file. You do already specify to use javascript code by importing the file in `<script setup />`, so the compiler knows that the content of the `.js`-file contains JavaScript code.

It is similar to the `CSS`-file: Just delete the HTML-tags (`<script>` and `</script>`) from the beginning and the end of the `.js`-file, and you should be fine.

If this does not work, the error message says that `script setup` cannot be used with external file imports, so you might be forced to write the JavaScript code directly into your `.vue`-component-file.

Comment: Hmm, I tried to do as you suggested, but I get an error: [vite] Internal server error: <script setup> cannot use the "src" attribute because its syntax will be ambiguous outside of the component.  For sure it should be a way to add an external .js setup file.

Comment: This is not possible, for more information, see [documentation for `script setup`](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#restrictions)